# Sorting variables alphabetically in a sed

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, sed

In short i have a bash script that finds all 5 letter words in the dictionary with a single duplicated letter. Im using sed to print out the letter that repeats and the letters that dont. I have to sort the letters that don't repeat in alphabetical order, and im not quite sure how

Here's my sed;

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\(.\)\(.*\)\2\(.*\)/\1\2\3\2\4  \2   \1\3\4 /'
```

### so i need to sort \1\3\4 by piping them into a read loop

UPDATE

```
grep '^[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]$' /usr/share/dict/words | 
grep '.*\(.\).*\1.*' |
grep -v '.*\(.\).*\1.*\1.*' |
grep -v '.*\(.\).*\(.\).*\1.*\2.*\1.*\2.*' |
grep -v '.*\(.\).*\(.\).*\1.*\2.*\2.*\1.*' |
grep -v '.*\(.\).*\(.\).*\1.*\1.*\2.*\2.*' |
sed 's/\(.*\)\(.\)\(.*\)\2\(.*\)/\1\2\3\2\4 \2 \1\3\4/' |
while read word dup nondup
    do sort -$nondup 
    front=$[nondup:1]
    middle=$[nondup:2]
    back=$[nondup:3]

    echo $word $dup $front$middle$back
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a sample dictionary of 5-letter words:

```
$ cat file
timey
terra
debby
ovolt
spell
```

Now, using your sed command, let's sort the output by the non-repeating letters:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)\(.\)\(.*\)\2\(.*\)/\1\2\3\2\4  \2   \1\3\4 /' file | sort -k3
timey
debby  b   dey 
spell  l   spe 
terra  r   tea 
ovolt  o   vlt
```

`sort -k3` sorts over the third column.

#### Above but also sort the non-recurring letters alphabetically

This solution adds a shell `while` loop in order to sort the non-recurring letters:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\(.\)\(.*\)\2\(.*\)/\1\2\3\2\4  \2   \1\3\4 /' file | while read word rep non
do
    non=$(echo "$non" | grep -o . | sort |tr -d "\n")
    echo "$word $rep $non"
done | sort -k3
```

On the same input, this produces the output:

```
timey  
terra r aet
debby b dey
spell l eps
ovolt o ltv
```

#### Primitive Method Suitable Only For Instructors

If I understand correctly, your instructor wants something like this:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\(.\)\(.*\)\2\(.*\)/\1\2\3\2\4  \2   \1\3\4 /' file | 
while read word rep non
do
    [ "$non" ] || continue # skip any word that lacks a repeating letter
    front=${non:0:1}
    middle=${non:1:1}
    back=${non:2:1}
    if [[ "$front" < "$middle" ]] && [[ "$front" < "$back" ]]
    then
        [[ "$middle" < "$back" ]] && non=$front$middle$back || non=$front$back$middle
    elif [[ "$middle" < "$front" ]] && [[ "$middle" < "$back" ]]
    then
        [[ "$front" < "$back" ]] && non=$middle$front$back || non=$middle$back$front
    elif [[ "$back" < "$front" ]] && [[ "$back" < "$middle" ]]
    then
        [[ "$front" < "$middle" ]] && non=$back$front$middle || non=$back$middle$front
    else
        echo "ERROR"
    fi
    echo "$word $rep $non"
done | sort -k3
```

This method requires `bash`.

Comment: thanks for the great answer John, but i should've mentioned that the words still have to remain in alphabetical order as well, heres an example of what it should look like
debby b dey
ovolt o ltv
spell l eps
terra r aet

Comment: @ConnerNey That does change things substantially.  I added a shell loop to handle that.  See updated answer.

Comment: Check my updated code, my instructor sent me an email saying to use the format shown in my code to solve this, any help? I'm not quite sure how to sort the nondup before substringing it, or would i have to substring first then sort then echo? regardless I'm not sure how to go about doing it

Comment: @ConnerNey My code properly sorted the nondups.  Why would the instructor disapprove?  Nevertheless, I added a really primitive method if that is what he wants.  (The complete `sed` pipeline that the instructor provides to precede the `while` is good.  I don't use it in my example only because I am using a limited dictionary.)

Comment: I really appreciate your help but i think we're having a mis communication. My Updated code is what i have, it does the same thing your primitive code does. the problem is in the while loop that i'm piping sed into. the loop has to sort the last 3 variables. without losing the alphabetical ordering of the actual words of the dictionary, is that clear? I'm not very good at explaining

Comment: Replace `sort -k3` with `sort`.  Is that the output that you want?

Comment: It's still not the correct output. But thank you very much. I'll just meet with my instructor tomorrow and try to understand where he wants me to go from here.. he's very strange about his bash assignments. Thanks again John

Answer (score 1):

You can simply modify your `sed command` and pipe to sort to sort the 3 characters most efficiently. In addition to John's answer, if your question wants only the remnants sorted:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(.\)\(.*\)\2\(.*\)/\1\3\4/' stack/dat/dicta.dat | sort
```

**input:**

```
$ cat stack/dat/dicta.dat
aback
abaft
abase
abash
abask
abate
```

**output:**

```
$ sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(.\)\(.*\)\2\(.*\)/\1\3\4/' stack/dat/dicta.dat | sort
bck
bft
bse
bsh
bsk
bte
```

If you want the full output sorted, then calling `sort` following your original `sed` with option `-k3` is the correct way.